# how to install gensim on windows 8.1

Tags: python, numpy, gensim

I just got acquainted with gensim and I tried to install it. I performed  any steps is written in page https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html but I could not install it. I have installed python 2.7, scipy, numpy successfully on windows 8.1 64bit, but when I run setup.py in gensim it doesn't run.

Please help me I need to gensim Immediately and tell me installation steps with More details and other software that needs to be installed before it.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Gensim depends on scipy and numpy.You must have them installed prior to installing gensim.Simple way to install gensim in windows is,
open cmd and type

pip install -U gensim

Or download gensim for windows from

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim
then run
python setup.py test
python setup.py install

Comment: thanks i have downloaded gensim for windows from this site but when i run setup,it dosen't run and when i type pip install -U gensim ,it get this error : pip is not recognized as an internal or external command,i can't install pip

Comment: To install pip, securely download get-pip.py   from  https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/  then run  python get-pip.py

Comment: now I don't know how to work with gensim and type its commands,if there is a website or paper to learn it tell me,I am confuzed

Comment: Please follow gensim website for tutorial.  https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html . Its easy.I have implemented concepts like LDA, LSA, H-LDA , SVD etc. Please click tick mark if you have installed gensim :)

Comment: I can help you with commands in gensim. Please point out where you are facing problem.

Comment: hi,I can't run gensim ,It is installed ok but I don't know how to work and run it where and type its command,please guide me I am confused

Comment: can you screenshot from environment gensim and its steps one project??

Comment: I have this setup: Python version = 3.6.0, Numpy version = 1.12.0, Scipy version = 0.19.0, Gensim version = 2.1.0. However when I import gensim I get the warning `Slow version of gensim.models.doc2vec is being used`. So then I try conda install -c anaconda gensim=2.1.0 I get the error `PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:` I have a c compiler, so I dont understand why this is happening. Can anyone please advise? Thank you