# How to install gensim on windows

Tags: python, gensim

Not able to install gensim on windows.Please help me I need to gensim Immediately and tell me installation steps with More details and other software that needs to be installed before it. thanks

Comment: This Question is already asked Before refer to this link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200360/how-to-install-gensim-on-windows-8-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200360/how-to-install-gensim-on-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gensim` depends on `scipy` and `numpy`.You must have them installed prior to installing `gensim`. Simple way to install `gensim` in windows is, open cmd and type

```
pip install -U gensim
```

Or download `gensim` for windows from

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim

then run

```
python setup.py test  
python setup.py install
```

Comment: i wanna install gensim offline would you help me?what should i do exactly?my system is not connected to internet.

Answer (score 8):

First you need to install `NumPy` then `SciPy` and then `Gensim` (assuming you already have `Python` installed). I used `Python 3.4` as I find it easier to install `SciPy` using version 3.4.

**Step 1) Install Numpy:**

Download `numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

*note that in `cp34-cp34m` 34 is version of `Python` you are using. So download appropriate file*

Open command prompt and go the folder in which you just downloaded the file and install `Numpy` using following command:

> pip install numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl

You should get *successfully installed numpy* message

**Step 2) Install SciPy:**

Follow the same link as above and download the `scipy‑0.19.1‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl` file.
Install it using the same instructions than in Step 1 but with this file name. The command is the following:

> pip install scipy‑0.19.1‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl

You should get this message *successfully installed scipy*

**Step 3)  Install gensim:**

Follow the link in step 1 and download `gensim‑2.3.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl` (the appropriate version for your system)
Install it using the instructions in Step 1 (with this file name) with following command:

> pip install gensim‑2.3.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl

You should get this message *successfully installed gensim*

Now in a `Python` shell try:

> import gensim

It should be successfully imported

**NOTES:** 
Make sure *pip* is in your environment variables (add *C:\python34\scripts* to your environment variable).

Make sure to download all the packages according to the `Python` version you are using.

Comment: This is the first clear explanation I've found with the good links and tips etc. Worked on the first try!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this a bit today trying to figure out if I needed a python 2.7 environment or if I could use my 3.5.  I ended up doing this from an Anaconda 3.5 install:

conda install -c anaconda gensim=0.12.4

After a few hours of trying various things, suddenly it all worked on 3.5.  My error was that it kept failing to install Scipy.  I tried starting over with the conda install and just worked.

See: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/gensim

Comment: I have this setup: Python version = 3.6.0, Numpy version = 1.12.0, Scipy version = 0.19.0, Gensim version = 2.1.0. However when I import gensim I get the warning `Slow version of gensim.models.doc2vec is being used`. So then I try `conda install -c anaconda gensim=2.1.0` I get the error `PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:` I have a c compiler, so I dont understand why this is happening. Can anyone please advise? Thank you

Comment: @KillianTattan I keep seeing scipy pop up as the problem when doing Anaconda/Gensim related things.  I have taken to installing SciPy first, trying the conda install first and doing pip if that fails.  Once O get SciPy installed, then i go to the other libraries.  Sorry I don't have more help for you.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using anaconda where the installation of all the packages is very easy.

The command for installing genism and all of its necessary packages on windows using anaconda python 3.7 is below.

```
conda install -c anaconda gensim
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction on https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html which then successfully installed the fast version of Gensim (3.8.0) on Windows:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gensim
```

---

PS: 
The following did **NOT** install the fast version on Windows:

```
conda install gensim
```

Answer (score 0):

After attempting some of the above ideas, there was still a "hiccup" with gensim but the error was something else related to punkt. The following (where the interest is the second line)...

```
import nltk 
nltk.download('punkt') 
import numpy 
import scipy 
import gensim
```

...did the trick. I used conda and not pip but do not believe that mattered.

Versions: latest python
Machine: Windows 10 (latest updates as of 8/2020)