# Gensim installation with python3

Tags: python-3.5, gensim

I installed Gensim in python3

when I call gensim I got this error. Can someone help?

```
>>> import gensim


AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Comment: Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739250/how-to-install-gensim-on-windows

Comment: How did you install Python and gensim? What is your operating system? Are you working within a virtual environment, as is good practice? Is that really the only error shown? (Usually there would be more information about the stack frames & lines-of-code where the error happened.)