# Error with calling Numpy, Scipy, Gensim in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, gensim

Why when I call Numpy, Scipy, Gensim with python3 in linux I have the following error?

```
>import gensim
_concrete_types = {v.type for k, v in _concrete_typeinfo.items()}
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Comment: Hi, *AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type*, how did you exactly calls the numpy, scipy, or gensim? please provide some [mcve] code so people can try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: What is your operating system? How was Python and gensim installed? How are you running the line `import gensim`? Is that really the full error info displayed in response? (Are you the same person, or working on the same system/problem, the person who posted the similar question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187308/gensim-installation-with-python3> a day ago?)

Answer (score 1):

I've today observed this issue as well, but with tooling that depends only on pandas as numpy.

I've also seen a similar issue here: [AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type' upon importing tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200850/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-type-upon-importing-tensorflow)

I can't add this as a comment because I don't have sufficient reputation, so please forgive me.

*edit see the other thread for an answer: it's the new numpy version.