# Getting AttributeError during python library import

Tags: python, pandas, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda

I was using jupyter notebook using `pip` and all libraries were working fine. But from today, it suddenly started showing the following error on every library. I don't know what happened.

It is working fine in Conda.

```
import pandas as pd

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

c:\users\aamir siddiqui\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
     11 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     12     try:
---> 13         __import__(dependency)
     14     except ImportError as e:
     15         missing_dependencies.append(dependency)

c:\users\aamir siddiqui\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

c:\users\aamir siddiqui\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     55 from . import umath
     56 from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
---> 57 from . import numerictypes as nt
     58 multiarray.set_typeDict(nt.sctypeDict)
     59 from . import numeric

c:\users\aamir siddiqui\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py in <module>()
    109 )
    110 
--> 111 from ._type_aliases import (
    112     sctypeDict,
    113     sctypeNA,

c:\users\aamir siddiqui\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_type_aliases.py in <module>()
     61         _concrete_typeinfo[k] = v
     62 
---> 63 _concrete_types = {v.type for k, v in _concrete_typeinfo.items()}
     64 
     65 

c:\users\aamir siddiqui\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_type_aliases.py in <setcomp>(.0)
     61         _concrete_typeinfo[k] = v
     62 
---> 63 _concrete_types = {v.type for k, v in _concrete_typeinfo.items()}
     64 
     65 

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type' upon importing tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200850/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-type-upon-importing-tensorflow)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnumpy%5D+AttributeError%3A+%27tuple%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27type%27

Answer (score 1):

have you update tesorflow to 1.12?
i encountered the same situation when i udate tensor flow to 1.12.
So i `pip install tensorflow==1.10.0` ,it worked.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.