# Making Gensim FAST_VERSION work on Windows 10 (Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I am running Gensim with Python 3.6 on Windows 10. I have tried installing Visual Studio 2019 and MinGW (through TDM-GCC). I have uninstalled and reinstalled Gensim after both installations. I also did that after uninstalling and reinstalling Cython.

Regardless, it's not able to run the C extension, so I am stuck with the slower Numpy code.

I am not sure where the trouble lies, and I have run out of ideas on how to proceed. What can I do to make progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option of using a Linux/UNIX-based OS, much of the Python/scientific stack is going to be easier to get working there, as the bulk of development, testing, and use happens on non-Windows OSes.

Using a package manager that's well-maintained for Windows OSes, like `conda`, may succeed in installing highly-optimized versions of `gensim` (& other packages), where default instructions & local tinkering does not. In some cases, this may be because it is able to use trusted, pre-compiled binaries/libraries.

In some cases, pre-compiled Python "Wheel" (`.whl`) packages may help. I can't vouch for these, but there appear to be a set of these at:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gensim

(This [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45613490/130288), which I also can't vouch for, may help guid a wheels-based installation.)

If you absolutely need to build locally, for example because you are customizing gensim's optimized code, debugging the issue would require paying close attention to the individual errors reported during installation and researching/addressing each one-by-one.

Comment: Yes, using conda did indeed help. However, I am not sure if I should accept this answer since it technically doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: What was the other part of the question, besides getting a good `FAST_VERSION` working on Windows 10? Are you still stuck with the slower Numpy code? Do you still need help to "make progress"? (It's not clear on what, from the question.)

Comment: No, you're right. I confused this question with another question I asked on this topic which is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

2 options.

option 1) remove pip's cache and reinstall gensim.

```
pip --no-cache-dir install gensim
```

option 2) https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Create a distutils.cfg file with the following contents in the folder \Lib\distutils in Python install directory :

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler=mingw32
```