# Gensim package installation/word2vec not recognised

Tags: python, pip, conda, gensim

`from gensim.models import Word2Vec`

results in the following error
ImportError: cannot import name 'Word2Vec' from 'gensim.models' (unknown location)

`from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec`

results in the same error

After deleting all conda installations of this package, pip uninstalling gensim, pip installing gensim and pip install --upgrade gensim, I can finally do

`import gensim`
but when I try to use `gensim.models.Word2Vec` it results in the error:
AttributeError: module 'gensim.models' has no attribute 'Word2Vec'

Edit: updated Numpy and Scipy as well

Note: I am using a jupyter notebook that I run from my local machine. I have not had this problem using Pycharm where I was running gensim from a conda env (but I'm working on a group project in notebook so it would be nice if I didn't constantly have to copy paste between these 2 workspaces...)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: seems a problem with the installation. please try suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739250/42346 even if not on Windows OS, definitely check if numpy and scipy are present before attempting gensim install.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to restart your kernel after the installation and see if it works. Then, check that your are in the right virtual environment. Then, please check you gensim version. In a notebook cell run

```
import gensim
gensim.__version__ # should be 4.1.2. If it's not update via pip.
```

You can also manually inspect if gensim.models.word2vec is actually there. In a notebook cell run

```
gensim.__path__
```

and go to the folder. Here you can see if there's indeed a folder named models and a script named word2vec. If not, there's something wrong with your installation. Hope this helps a bit.